# How do you use the central limit theorem to approximate the sample mean when pdf f(x)=2x

Tags: statistics, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_{1},\ldots, X_{n}$ be a collection of independent identically distributed (iid) samples from a population with pdf

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
2x,&\text{if } 0 \leq x \leq 1\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

How can I use the central limit theorem (CLT) to find the approximate distribution for the sample mean, $\bar{X}_n = \tfrac{1}{n}(X_1+\ldots+X_n)$, as $n$ approaches infinity?

(the answer is $\mathcal{N}(2/3, 1/18n)$ I just don't know how to get there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can apply the central limit theorem in your case. First, you need to determine the mean and variance of your distribution. Let $X$ be a random variable that follows the given distribution with pdf $f$. Then,

$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_0^1 2x^2 \mathrm{d}x = 2/3
$$

and

$$
\operatorname{Var}[X] = \int_0^1 (x-\tfrac{2}{3})^2 2x^2\mathrm{d}x
= \frac{1}{18}.
$$

Then, the Lindeberg–Lévy CLT says that since $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are iid samples, which follow the given distribution (which has finite variance), then

$$
\sqrt{n} (\bar{X}_n - \tfrac{2}{3}) \to \mathcal{N}(0, \tfrac{1}{18})
$$

in distribution, where $\bar{X}_n = \tfrac{1}{n}(X_1 + \ldots + X_n)$ is the sample average.

This means that, for large $n$, the distribution of $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n - 2/3)$ can be approximated by $\mathcal{N}(0, 1/18)$, or, equivalently, the distribution of $\bar{X}_n$ can be approximated by

$$
\bar{X}_n \overset{\text{approx.}}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(\tfrac{2}{3}, \tfrac{1}{18 n}).
$$